# Special case of canonical embedding

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

The exist some way to prove that the particular canonical embedding $J_{L^2}:L^2 \to (L^2)'' $ defined by

$$ J_{L^2}(f)(\varphi)=\varphi(f)\,\,\,\forall \varphi \in (L^2)'\,\,\ \text{and}\,\,\forall f \in L^2$$

is an isometry without using the Hahn-Banach Theorem?

Here $L^2$ is the special case of the usual $L^p$ space for $p=2$.

Comment: This is the Riesz representation theorem for the Hilbert space $L^2$.